# open audio formats and audio synthesis using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

1. How can I open different audio formats(except .mp3 and .wav) using Naudio and C#?
2. How can I create audio synthesis unsing Naudio and C#?(I mean how to get the sound frequency and other data necesary for audio synthesis).

P.S. I've looked at this tutorial series

http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/02/introduction-to-using-naudio.html

and this one

http://www.giawa.com/tutorials/?p=19o

Comment: What kind of audio synthesis?  It ranges from sine at 100hz to text-to-speech...

Answer (score 0):

1. In addition to MP3 and WAV, NAudio can also open AIFF and WMA files with the AiffFileReader and WmaFileReader classes. Beyond that, you will have to write your own WaveStream derived class to read other formats.
2. See my tutorial on [how to play a sine wave in NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html), which will show you the basics of how to get started with audio synthesis in NAudio.